# Flutter dart: retorno de valor para uma classe

Tags: flutter, dart, método, firestore

Ao chamar o método `callReadTotal()`, a variável global `tot` recebe o valor e o mesmo imprime sem problemas seu resultado dentro dele. No entanto, na classe `ThemesList` que o chamou, a variável recebe `null`.

Alguém poderia me dizer o que falta aí? Desde já obrigado.

```
callReadTotal() async {
  await firestoreInstance.collection("causas").get().then((value) {
    tot = value.docs.length;   
  });
  print(tot);   
}
```

```
int tot;
FirebaseFirestore firestoreInstance = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
class ThemesList extends StatelessWidget {
  List<FlatButton> _getButtonBar(context) {
    callReadTotal(); //chamando o método
    print(tot); //recebe sempre null.
     .
     .
     .
```

Answer (score 0):

Você não está trabalhando corretamente com códigos assíncronos em Dart.

A função assíncrona `callReadTotal()` retorna um `Future<void>`:

```dart
Future<void> callReadTotal() async {
  await firestoreInstance.collection("causas").get().then((value) {
    tot = value.docs.length;   
  });
  print(tot);   
}
```

Consequentemente `_getButtonBar()` também se torna assíncrona e deve aguardar `await` a execução de `callReadTotal()`.

```dart
Future<List<FlatButton>> _getButtonBar(context) async {
    await callReadTotal();
    print(tot);
}
```

Isso resolve seu problema. Porém, você não deve trabalhar assim com variáveis globais. Retorne esse `tot` na função `callReadTotal()`:

```dart
Future<int> callReadTotal() async {
  return await firestoreInstance.collection("causas").get().then((value) {
    tot = value.docs.length;   
  });  
}

Future<List<FlatButton>> _getButtonBar(context) async {
    int tot = await callReadTotal();
    print(tot);
}
```

Recomendo a leitura do funcionamento de [programação assíncrona](https://dart.dev/codelabs/async-await).